# Problema variavel global angular

Tags: javascript, html, http

```
app.controller('controllerPrincipal', function($scope, $http){


        var resultado;
        $http({method: 'GET', params: {id: 2}, url: 'url'}).success(function(data)
        {
            // limpando o retorno
            var p = data.search("{")-1;
            var res = data.substring(76);
            var f = res.search('<');
            dados = data.substring(p, p+f);
            resultado = JSON.parse(dados);
        });

        console.log(resultado);


});
```

Quando dou um `console.log(resultado)`, fora do http ele me retorna undefined, quando do um `console.log()` dentro do http ainda ele me retorna o resultado correto..

nao esta com a url pois e de um cliente meu.. mas a url o retorno esta ok, so quando eu pego fora nao esta rolando a variavel resultado.

Alguem tem uma LUZ?

Comment: Luz florescente ou incandescente?

Comment: A que funciona kkkk

Comment: Ficou confuso tente explicar melhor

Comment: dentro do $http, eu armazeno o data na variavel resultado, como acesso a variavel resultado externo, fora do $http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece porque o `$http` executa uma requisição assíncrona, então o `resultado` no momento em que você *loga* ele não foi preenchido ainda. Ele só vai ser preenchido depois que a requisição terminar **e** no seu caso se for com sucesso. Aliás você deveria criar um serviço para fazer isso e não dentro do controle, mas isso é uma outra história.

Para você utilizar esses dados, onde quer que você esteja usando, você tem que dar continuidade dentro do `success`. Por exemplo: Se você usa isso em uma lib de terceiro, tem que chama-la lá dentro, ou em qualquer função, passando esse resultado.

Ficou claro?

**Atualização**

No seu caso, para incluir um serviço você pode usar o `factory` ou `service`, ambos [providers](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers). Esse exemplo usa o primeiro:

```
app.factory('controllerPrincipalService', function($http, $q) {
    return {
            getResultado: function(id) 
            {
                var deferred = $q.defer();

                $http(
                {
                    method: 'GET', 
                    url: 'url',
                    data: {id:id}
                }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) 
                {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) 
                {
                    deferred.reject(status);
                });

                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
});
```

Assim você separa as camadas e deixa as requisições fora do controller, o que deixa seu código bem mais organizado. Seu controller ficaria assim:

```
app.controller('controllerPrincipal', ["$scope", "controllerPrincipalService", function($scope, $http) {
    controllerPrincipalService.getResultado(id).then(function(dados)
    {
        // limpando o retorno
        var p = data.search("{")-1;
        var res = data.substring(76);
        var f = res.search('<');
        dados = data.substring(p, p+f);
        resultado = JSON.parse(dados);
    });
}]);
```

Note a injeção de dependência que o controller possui `["$scope", "controllerPrincipalService"`. Isso te dá no scopo o serviço completo, que por sua vez, retorna um [`deferred`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q). Note também que o controller agora não trabalha mais com o callback `success` mas sim com o `then`, o que é chamado de [promisses](http://liamkaufman.com/blog/2013/09/09/using-angularjs-promises/). O `success` e o `error` ficam no serviço para serem tratados lá. Mas a idéia é a mesma, você tem que continuar seu fluxo a partir do callback `then`.

**Atualização 2**

Uma forma melhor de *dar um parse* nesse xml pode ser assim:

```
xmlparser = new DOMParser();
xmlDoc = xmlparser.parseFromString(dados, "text/xml");
var string = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("string")[0].innerHTML;
var json = JSON.parse(string);
```

[Neste artigo](http://toptechtutor.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/javascript-xml-processing.html) tem uma versão cross-browser(o código acima provavelmente não irá funcionar no IE). E [neste post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/649655/1267304) tem como fazer em jQuery, que é bem mais simples.

Comment: Nao ficou muito claro, mas qual seria a forma correta ? seria criar um service ? estou iniciando agora com angular poderia me dar um exemplo por favor ?, Abraços

Comment: @LucasMoura Atualizei minha resposta. Espero não complicar mais sua vida, mas eu também sou novo no Angular e esse exemplo que estou usando no meu primeiro projeto na minha empresa. Seria legal se você me falasse como você usa esse resultado e como ele é, pra eu poder te ajudar mais.

Comment: Bela explicação Márcio, vlw meu brother... Nao sei o que seria esse deferred e promisses mas vou pesquisar, vlw pela explicação abracos..  Esse resultado, eu vou jogar em slides, pois ele e uma tela de apresentacão de suites de hoteis... Outra duvida... repare que fiz para limpar o retorno, pois o retorno do meu webservice ele me traz o json dentro de um <xml> que tem um <string> ai sim vem o json entao esta assim <xml><string>[{JSON}]</string></xml>, tem alguma forma mais pratica para limpar esse retorno ? Essa maneira foi a que fiz pois sou novato em js, se tiver um luz tmb rsrs... abraços

Comment: @LucasMoura atualizei denovo, com uma forma mais elegante de tratar seu xml. Boa sorte cara!

Comment: Vlw, abraços...

Answer (score 0):

Outra duvida Marcio..

```
 controllerPrincipalService.getResultado(id).then(function(dados)
    {
        // limpando o retorno
        var p = data.search("{")-1;
        var res = data.substring(76);
        var f = res.search('<');
        dados = data.substring(p, p+f);
        resultado = JSON.parse(dados);
    });
```

por exemplo eu estou utilizando esse service ai... beleza...
caso eu precise usar o resultado em outro lugar, por exemplo uma funcao abaixo desse service dentro da controle seria possivel ?

Exemplo;

```
 controllerPrincipalService.getResultado(id).then(function(dados)
    {
        // limpando o retorno
        var p = data.search("{")-1;
        var res = data.substring(76);
        var f = res.search('<');
        dados = data.substring(p, p+f);
        resultado = JSON.parse(dados);
    });

    function pegaResultado(resultado){
        ///trabalhar com o resultado do service a cima.
        console.log(resultado);

    }
```

O porque disso...

Pq eu preciso fazer um setInterval, no qual ele sempre vai ficar executando o service getResultado, caso tenha alteracao no meu webservice.. entendeu ?
vlw

Comment: Vá em edit e adicione sua "outra dúvida" na pergunta original, especificando que é uma nova dúvida (não apague a antiga). Assim fica mais fácil de obter uma resposta.